# How to view differences between two html documents?

Tags: html, eclipse, github, collaboration, etherpad

I'm working on a help system with hundreds of pages written in HTML.
I want to give those HTML pages to multiple people so they can make changes.
Before I upload their modified documents, I need some way (such as color coding) to check and fix their changes. For example, I want to see all the changes marked in red or some other visual cue. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Compare in Eclipse.. no?

Comment: Notepad++ with Diff plugin... No?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Use Eclipse as Diff Tool](http://heikobehrens.net/2008/12/02/use-eclipse-as-diff-tool/)

Comment: @MehandiHassan [Google](https://www.google.si/search?q=code%20diff%20web) is your friend.

Answer (score 3):

Use a diff tool. I really like [SourceGear's DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/), and it is free!

Answer (score 1):

Diff will work as others have said.

However, I'd be leery as an admin to be having to deal with hundreds of pages of HTML edited by multiple people.  This is SCREAMING for a CMS or Document Management System of sorts to deal with exactly this problem.  It would be more than easy enough to save each version (as Stackoverflow does on edits) so that you could pick and choose between the best ones.  Another huge advantage would be eliminating the repetitive nature of common elements, such as headers, doctype declarations, etc.  I wouldn't even want to begin to think how much fun it would be to try to unify all that and get it 100% compliant....

There are Help systems out there for just this purpose if you're not up to setting this up yourself.  My company uses Kayako, but there are dozens to choose from, many free.

Comment: Thanks bperson76. I did not mention in my question that I am using a CMS (RoboHelp) and the files generated by RoboHelp are html files. It is those files that I would like to use Diff on.

Comment: Right. And U can effectively compare two files at the same time. Maybe four at most. If the number is larger it may become overwhelming and you will be making lots of mistakes as a human.